# Xamarin UI Testing

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, ui-testing, xamarin-test-cloud

I would like to add UnitTest into my Xamarin app, I get the splash screen displaying on the Andriod emulator and then the landing page loads but the next page it seems to closes the app . I have break point around the Platform.Android and that hits but it never hit the end of that method. I added WaitTimes for 5 minutes and I will get the timeout exception

> Any idea why the app closes ?

```
  static class AppManager
{
    private const string ApkPath = @"C:\pathtoapkfile.apk";

    static IApp app;
    public static IApp App
    {
        get
        {
            if (app == null)
                throw new NullReferenceException("'AppManager.App' not set. Call 'AppManager.StartApp()' before trying to access it.");
            return app;
        }
    }

    static Platform? platform;
    public static Platform Platform
    {
        get
        {
            if (platform == null)
                throw new NullReferenceException("'AppManager.Platform' not set.");
            return platform.Value;
        }

        set { platform = value; }
    }

    public static void StartApp()
    {
        if (Platform == Platform.Android)
        {
            app = ConfigureApp
                .Android
                .ApkFile(ApkPath)
                .WaitTimes(new WaitTimes())
                .StartApp(AppDataMode.Clear);
        }

        if (Platform == Platform.iOS)
        {
            app = ConfigureApp
                .iOS
                .StartApp(AppDataMode.Clear);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Platform is obsolete. If you are using up to date mono you should use Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android. Currently posted code prevents me for further speculations

Comment: Is your problem resolved?

Comment: I am still having problems I have updated the post with the code in AppManager.

Comment: Do you mean the test app launched successfully and then it looks like stuck? If the app is not launch successfully, I would recommend you check the path of apk, look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42216636/xamarin-ui-test-unable-to-load-the-native-apk-path-that-i-point-to).